# Parsing SOAP request returns null - ORACLE SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, soap

I have been trying to Parse the values in SOAP XML web request content which was present in a CLOB type column. But it is returning NULL, Please take a look into the below select query and suggest me what to do to get the correct values.

```
select
    a.*
from migt_pm_messages mpm
     , xmltable(
            xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as  "soapenv",
             'http://pmts.ofss.com/ws/PMBookTransferSIService' as "pmb"),
              '/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/pmb:settleResponse/settleReturn'
             passing XMLType(mpm.msg)
             columns
                 TXN_VALUE_DATE date path 'pmb:TXN_VALUE_DATE'
                 , NETWORK_CODE varchar2(20) path 'pmb:NETWORK_CODE'
                 , EXCH_RATE number path 'pmb:EXCH_RATE'
                 , SOURCE_REF_NO varchar2(10) path 'pmb:SOURCE_REF_NO',
                   USER_REF_NO varchar2(10) path 'pmb:USER_REF_NO',
                   SOURCE_CODE varchar2(10) path 'pmb:SOURCE_CODE',
                   TXN_BRANCH varchar2(10) path 'pmb:TXN_BRANCH',
                   TXN_BOOKING_DATE date path 'pmb:TXN_BOOKING_DATE'
                   ) a
where rownum = 1;
```

Thank you.

Comment: How can we tell?  You need to edit the question and post a valid xml payload that was used.

Comment: You might just need the last part of the XPath to be `/pmb:settleReturn`, but without seeing sample XML (and expected results for that XML) we can't really tell.